# Oracle SQL Count function

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I am hoping someone can advise on the below please?
I have some code (below), it is pulling the data I need with no issues. I have been trying (in vain) to add a COUNT function in here somewhere. The output I am looking for would be a count of how many orders are assigned to each agent. I tried a few diffent things based on other questions but can't seem to get it correct. I think I am placing the COUNT 'Agent' statement and the GROUP BY in the wrong place. Please can someone advise? (I am using Oracle SQL Developer).

```
select
n.ordernum as "Order",
h.employee as "Name"
from ordermgmt n, orderheader h
where h.ordernum = n.ordernum
and h.employee_group IN ('ORDER.MGMT')
and h.employee is NOT NULL
and n.percentcomplete = '0'
and h.order_status !='CLOSED'
```

Output I am looking for would be, for example:

```
Name         Orders Assigned
Bob                 3
Peter               6
John                2
```

Thank you in advance

| Name | Total |
| --- | --- |
|  | 49 |
|  | 49 |
|  | 49 |
|  | 49 |
|  | 49 |
| John | 4 |
| John | 4 |
| John | 4 |
| John | 4 |
| Peter | 2 |
| Peter | 2 |
| Bob | 3 |
| Bob | 3 |
| Bob | 3 |

for example. so there are 49 blank rows summed up as 49 in the Total column. I did not add the full 49 blank columns to save space

Comment: Edit your question with a sample of data. Also I don't see any group by or count in your code.

Comment: That looks like a simple aggregation. How are `ordermgmt` and `orderheader` related? One row per `ordernum` in `orderheader` and many rows per `ordernum` in `orderheader`? What do the tables represent? `orderheader` is an order?, and `ordermgmt` is what?

Comment: Sample data makes more sense, when you don't only show the result, but also the table data that leads to this result. What would `orderheader` and `ordermgmt` contain, so you get the result you are showing?

Comment: You are using an antique join syntax by the way that makes your query look like it was written in the 1980s. Please use exlicit joins instead (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, etc.).

Comment: Thank you Thorsten, I will update the join type, I am rather new here so still learning. `orderheader` is the order details and `ordermgmt` is the admin table in the backend. The relationship is `ordernum` to `ordernum`. I am trying to add the output but not sure how to do so

Comment: I'm glad you got an answer that works for you. I must admit I wouldn't have been able to give an answer, because the task is not clear to me. Next time you write a request, it will help if you explain the tables. This means especially that you tell us the tables' keys. I asked you this, but it seems you didn't understand my question. You say that the table called orderheader is actually not the order header (where we would have the order date and the supplier and/or recipient), but the order details (which is usually the lines in an order, i.e. the ordered products with amounts and prices)...

Comment: ... I suppose that your wording is just different from the common wording and the table is in fact the order header and there simply are no detail rows. In an order header the ordernum is the unique key, in an order detail the ordernum can occur more than once. What an order management table is, I still don't understand. Is it a kind of history of order status? Or is it the order split in parts, where half of the order is delivered and the other half still due for instance? You see that you gave way too few information...

Comment: ... We don't even see sample data. I suggested you show us the table data that leads to the expected shown result, but you didn't. Instead you posted another result that doesn't seem to have to do with your query at all. So, next time please don't only show the result, but show the table data, too. It is uncommon by the way not to have an employee table, bbut only employee names in your order table. Thus a mere typo like Jhon instead of John can lead to not finding the order when looking for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be easier with sample data and expected output, but maybe you are looking for something like this

```
select
  n.ordernum as "Order",
  h.employee as "Name",
  count(*) over (partition by h.employee) as OrdersAssigned
from ordermgmt n, orderheader h
where h.ordernum = n.ordernum
  and h.employee_group IN ('ORDER.MGMT')
  and h.employee is NOT NULL
  and n.percentcomplete = '0'
  and h.order_status !='CLOSED'
```

Comment: Thank you James, this one works better however I now have multiple blank lines in the employee field. The count is working however it repeats. For example John has 4 orders assigned.  so I have  John  4  four times in a row

Comment: "I now have multiple blank lines in the employee field" => They should be present before this query, I just added the `OrderAssigned` field.  "I have John 4 four times in a row" => If you want to keep the `Order` field, you cannot get a single view of John. Remove this field, and use the query provided by the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `COUNT` (as other aggregate functions) is simple.

If you want to add an aggregate function, please group all scalar fields in the `GROUP BY` clause.

So, in the `SELECT` you can manage field1, field2, count(1) and so on but you must add in group by (after where conditions) field1, field2

Try this:

```
select
h.employee as "Name",
count(1) as "total"
from ordermgmt n, orderheader h
where h.ordernum = n.ordernum
and h.employee_group IN ('ORDER.MGMT')
and h.employee is NOT NULL
and n.percentcomplete = '0'
and h.order_status !='CLOSED'
GROUP BY h.employee
```

Comment: @sagi You're right. I've removed the first column